# Can't center nav menu and can't get separator line in between items

Tags: html, css

I'm having some trouble centering nav menu under everything else and also the separator line isn't sitting centered either between the two menu items.

CSS

```
    .center{
    width: 450px;
    height: 500px;
    /*margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    position:relative;*/
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
margin-left:-225px;
margin-top:-250px;}



#navbar {

    padding:0;
    margin-left: 0 auto;
    margin-right: 0 auto;}

#navbar li {
    float: left;
    list-style:none;
    width: 100px;}

#navbar a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#FFF;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 0;}

#navbar li + li {
    background: url('separator.gif') no-repeat top left;
}
```

Here is the http://jsfiddle.net/elroyz/GPgPF/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of floating your `navbar li` make them `display:inline-block`:

```
#navbar li {
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    width: 100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GPgPF/3/

Comment: thanks man thats perfect! i didnt even notice that i had floated left with it.

Answer (score 1):

change you css to this:

```
#navbar {
    width: 100%;
    padding:0;
}

#navbar li {
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    width: 100px;
}
```